# WordPress server not available after domain change

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, dns

I am hosting a WordPress website on an AWS EC2-instance.

I have an EIP set up and the AWS address is: 52.48.53.181

I have transferred a domain name from godaddy to AWS using route 53. I set up the 4 nameservers and created an A record set. The domain name is:

[www.wp360.com](http://www.wp360.com)

I logged into the Wordpress admin/general settings page and changed the site url to the following:

"Site Address (URL)": http://wp360.com

"WordPress Address (URL)":http://wp360.com

I now get an error message saying that the server is not found and I cannot load the page.

Wordpress is installed in /var/www/html

Any ideas?

Comment: If I do a whois on the domain it still shows Godaddy as the Registrar, are you sure the domain move was succesful?

Comment: I've just checked whois and the DNS is showing as my AWS account, unless I am reading it incorrectly.

Comment: You have an `A` record for `www.wp360.com` but there is no record for `wp360.com`

Comment: Ah. So I need to create an A record set for wp360.com, How do I do that? Doesn't it automatically populate the "www" anyway once I add the record? and do I need to delete the other `www.wp360.com` record?

Comment: Sorted. Changed the A record to `wp360.com` Thanks @DusanBajic

Comment: By the way, your site doesn't look good on big screens (>1908px width)

Comment: @GavinReynoldson Just ping your domain, has it resolved to new IP address? If yes, you should be able to browse your site.

Comment: @Emil Cheers. Still need to finish responsive elements.